# passando valor webapi para select html em angular 2

Tags: html, angular

eu tenho uma função em typescript que recebe um valor json da minha webapi, e preciso passar esse resultado para um select em html...

Service:

```
teste: teste[];
public getNomes(type: string, formGroup: FormGroup) {
    let params: HttpParams = undefined;
    params = new HttpParams().set('type', type);
    switch (type) {
        case "teste":
            params = params.set('cod', formGroup.controls['codigoCliente'].value);
            this.retornaNomeApi(API + '/Pesquisa/SelectPesquisa', params).subscribe(nome => {this.teste = nome.result});
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
 <select class="form-control" name="pedido">
        <option selected>Selecione...</option>
        <option *ngFor="let testes of teste">{{testes.cod}} - {{testes.nome}}</option>
      </select>
```

agradeço desde já :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que a melhor forma de fazer isso seria criando um reactive form.
Você poderia fazer da seguinte forma.

No HTML você poderia criar o form com um formGroup deste modo.

```
<form [formGroup]="form">` 
     <select class="form-control" formGroupName="pedido">
        <option selected>Selecione...</option>
        <option *ngFor="let testes of teste">{{testes.cod}} 
          {{testes.nome}}</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

No typescript você precisaria injetar a dependência de formBuilder e criar um FormGroup com o nome definido no [formGroup] do Html.

```
constructor(private fb:FormBuilder){
}
form: FormGroup;
```

E adicionar a instância de seu form dentro do método ngOnInit().

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.form = this.fb.group({ 
    pedido: ''
 })
}
```

No recebimento dos dados da sua WebAPI poderia adicionar o dado ao select da seguinte forma:

```
this.testes = res;
```

Aproveita e dá uma olhada na documentação dos reactive forms https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: cara, eu tentei dessa forma, porém continua sem receber nenhum retorno

Comment: Desculpa pela obviedade, mas há de fato o retorno dos dados da API?

Comment: sim, eu consigo ver o retorno da api no sources do navegador

Comment: Bruno, adiciona no HTML acima do form esse código

{{ form.value | json }} e vê se ele mostra o valor de pedido como vazio.

Comment: ele mostra vazio.

Comment: adiciona this.form.controls['pedido'].setValue(this.testes[0], { onlySelf: true }); 
dentro do subscribe da requisição. Teoricamente ele tem que definir a posição 0 do teu array como padrão do teu select